# Formula to update field with another field value if empty

Tags: formula

I have a custom field called:

Trader__c on the Account object.

I want to write a formula for that field:

If `Trader__c` is empty, then copy the `Name` field of Account in.

I was thinking of entering the following formula into the `Trader__c` field, but it's not a formula field, so it doesn't allow me to do it.

`IF(ISEMPTY(Trader__c),Trader__c == Name)`

Any ideas how to do it?
Tia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use **Workflow rule + field update** to achieve this

- Create a new workflow rule on Account
- Give it a name & description
- Select the Evaluation Criteria as the 3rd option
- Specify the rule criteria as Trader equals (leave the value as blank)
- Select the action as field update and choose Trader field as the field to be updated
- Choose use formula to set the new value and Enter the formula as **Name**

here's some help on how to create workflow rule & field update

[Creating Workflow Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules.htm)

[Defining Field Updates](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_defining_field_updates.htm&language=en_US)